# How to validate a text in textbox in mvc controller?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an MVC project and I am new in MVC. I need to validate texts entered in the `textbox`. The value of this `textbox` can be different (file, text, and URL) in different cases. In other words, I have a `enum` class `FileTypeEnum` with three different values. So, the input for this `textbox` needs to validate 3 times i.e. 3 different cases. I did validate this `textbox` when it is a file. I need to validate the text entered when `FileTypeEnum` is `text` i.e. 7.

```
//validate for file i.e. ResourceTypeId == 8
if (resource.ResourceTypeId == 8)
        {
            //already done work for it.
        }

        else if (resource.ResourceTypeId == 7)
        {

    // Trying to validate in here for texts 
    //  ^[a-zA-Z]+ ^.+\@.+\..+$

        }

  //validate for url i.e. ResourceTypeId == 9   
        else
        {
    // TODO
        }
```

Above code is for the controller where I need to do validation. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to validate on front end you do this with JavaScript.

On the back end you can derive your model from **IValidatableObject** and enforce all kinds of business rules. Sample is here: [Custom validation in MVC](http://www.itorian.com/2013/02/custom-validation-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately you need to use `RegularExpressionAttribute`. Check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information. But you need to create your own expression to suit your all `FileTypeEnum` three different types.